# T-SQL EXP Function Return different values for SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-function, exponential, exp

I have come across the `EXP` built in function in SQL Server and it seems this function returns different values in SQL Server 2012 environment compared to SQL Server 2005.

Running the code below returns different results in different environment. I'm trying to find out why there's the discrepancy and why the behavior of this function different from 2005 to 2012.

This is quite key to a project I'm working where a small difference in the calculations could have massive implications.

```
DECLARE @dec AS DECIMAL(20,18) 
DECLARE @flt AS FLOAT
SELECT @dec = (EXP(0.0267329893588985) - 1) 
SELECT @flt = (EXP(0.0267329893588985) - 1) 
SELECT @dec AS [Decimal], @flt AS [Float]
```

Results SQL Server 2012:

```
Decimal                       Float
---------------------------------------------
0.027093521247497640    0.0270935212474976
```

Results SQL Server 2005

```
Decimal                       Float
---------------------------------------------    
0.027093521247497860    0.0270935212474979
```

Comment: Both versions on the same machine and O/S ????

Comment: Both same bitness as well?

Comment: Yes I have tested it on my local machine windows 7 64 bit although I'm running sql 2005 express and sql 2012 developer edition.This might be a silly question but but Why would the bitness be an issue though?

Comment: No idea if it is mate. But it's not a huge difference, so I'd want to be sure sql version was the only difference in environment before I even bothered to investigate. I wouldn't bother with float at all either, looking for accuracy at that level of precision is a waste of effort.

Comment: Just googled and Exp expects a float and returns one, so your results from a decimal type include an implicit conversion to and from float. So your results on decimal are irrelevant. Couldn't find it but might be worth looking at what size float float defaults to in the two versions. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I have tested this on different machine and also on same machine with the same bitness but still the same issue. Because the EXP function return float type I wonder if it's down to how the two versions treat or complies float. On BOL
2005
The SQL Server float[(n)] data type complies with the SQL-92 standard for all values of n from 1 through 53. 
2012
The SQL Server float[(n)] data type complies with the ISO standard for all values of n from 1 through 53. 
The synonym for double precision is float(53) for both but does the SQL-92 & ISO Standard make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed due to bitness. x86; d == 0.027093521247497865 x64; d == 0.027093521247497643

And in turn this behavior is due to inherent  imprecision of FP numbers. If you are that concerned about this use high prec. libraries EXTERNAL to SQL. http://nongnu.org/hpalib/ is one external (C/C++) example.